# Systemd service - Python script inside Screen on boot

Tags: linux, python, gnu-screen, systemd

Im currently running a python script inside a Screen session through this script in rc.local:

```
screen -L -dmS pi python /home/pi/truck/main2.py &
```

But I would like it to run through systemd so I can restart it if the Python script crashes.

I tried creating a service in /systemd/system/myscript.service

```
[Unit]
Description=myscript
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -L -dmS pi  python /home/pi/truck/main2.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But it wont run my script inside the Screen session?

If I get a list of running screens it shows that the screen session "pi" is dead.

Comment: See me on unix.stackexchange.com, I would be glad to help you there!

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use Screen at all?

Comment: I'm running a Raspberry Pi headless and would like to SSH into my script. That's why I'm using Screen.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Type=simple` expects the service's main process to continue running forever. Your actual command, however, is telling Screen to do the opposite – start a new session and fork to background.

When Screen does that, systemd assumes the service has exited, and cleans up all leftover processes – including the "backgrounded" Screen process. (This doesn't even count as a "failure".)

To avoid that, either change type to `forking`, or the Screen `-dm` option to `-Dm`.

Comment: Changing the Type to forking did the trick. Thanks!